# How to JSON wrapper ( {"text": " ) from CSV response in WSO2

Tags: csv, wso2, transform, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2. I wrote Custom Java Class Mediator to transform JSON request to CSV format. I have a proxy service to SFTP the generated CSV file to a (MoveIT) folder.

Custom Mediator converts the JSON request properly to CSV format. But, when send the CSV file using transport.vfs.replyfilename to the endpoint, I see the 'text' wrapper as below in the CSV file:

```
{"text":"1,F20175_A.CSV,20200623135039\n2,123456789,2017-MO-BX-0048,123456789,987654321,Y/N,C/A,20190101,20201231,20190930,75000,44475.86,15563.52,0.00,15563.52,0.00,60039.38,14960.62,60039.38,0.00,20191218\n3,1,999999999\n"}
```

I set contentType, MessageType properties "text/plain". I also used vfs.ContentType to set to text/plain as below:
text/plain

I know I am missing something. Has anybody come across this issue in WSO EI 6.6? Should I go ahead and write Custom Message Formatter? Any tips?

I want the output to be written as:

```
1,F20169_A.CSV,20200617153638
2,123456789,2017-MO-BX-0048,123456789,987654321,Y/N,C/A,20190101,20201231,20190930,75000,44475.86,15563.52,0.00,15563.52,0.00,60039.38,14960.62,60039.38,0.00,20191218
3,1,999999999
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that after converting to the CSV format the result is available within a text tag. Therefore using the file connector [1] when you write to the file access the text content using  //text() XPath. Please refer to the following sample configuration of inputContent.

```
<fileconnector.create>
    <filePath>{$ctx:filePath}</filePath>
     <inputContent>{//text()}</inputContent>
    <encoding>{$ctx:encoding}</encoding>
    <setTimeout>{$ctx:setTimeout}</setTimeout>
    <setPassiveMode>{$ctx:setPassiveMode}</setPassiveMode>
    <setSoTimeout>{$ctx:setSoTimeout}</setSoTimeout>
    <setUserDirIsRoot>{$ctx:setUserDirIsRoot}</setUserDirIsRoot>
    <setStrictHostKeyChecking>{$ctx:setStrictHostKeyChecking}</setStrictHostKeyChecking>
</fileconnector.create>
```

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector#WorkingwiththeFileConnector-create